# Mandatory Content Control Box VB

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, ms-word

I would like to make a content control box mandatory in MS Word but can't find any way to do so. There are [six different events for content controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-content-controls) but none of them work for my case.

I have an MS Word template which has a custom column (confidentiality level of the document) added from Sharepoint. Generating the document from and saving it to Sharepoint works fine, but if the user does not fill out the confidentiality level the user shouldn't be able to save on Sharepoint. I need this for saving locally as well.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Word's basic design that can prevent a user from saving or closing a document if some criteria are not met. Doing so requires code that checks the document and cancels the action when necessary.

For VB.NET, that would be an add-in based on the IDT2Extensibilty interface, such as VSTO.

Or VBA in the documents or in an attached template would also be a possibility.

Both can work with events that fire when a document gets the command to save or close (or print, for that matter).